# Can't run jupyter notebook when using ssh

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh

New to linux and setting up my first system to run python and deep learning. I've got 16.04 Ubuntu, Anaconda, Python 3, Juypter notebook, and all my deep learning libraries installed and they work from my linux box. I've set up one user which is me.

I want to be able to access them from my mac laptop from elsewhere on my home network (eventually from anywhere, but baby steps). I installed openssh, configured the ports on my wireless router, and I am able to connect to the my linux box from my mac using the account and password that I set up. (Still working on installing keys and disabling password login, but again, baby steps.)

From my ssh session, I am able to update the system, edit files, shutdown, etc. but when I type `jupyter notebook` I get a **command not found** message.

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: *"using the account and password that I set up"* - is that a separate account from the one that you use normally?

Comment: Yes it is the same one. There is only one account on my installation "rothrock."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally basic thing! Logging in over ssh only runs the **.bash_profile** and not **.bashrc**. All my PATH directories for Anaconda and Jupyter were added to .bashrc. I followed [this advice](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) and added the following to my .bash_profile

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Now on to the next basic thing that I've messed up!